# Haskell types [Integer->Integer]

Tags: haskell

```
 y = [\a->a+3, \b->1 , \c->c*c]
```

I recognize function y has type of [Integer->Integer] , implies that it return list of function and each function takes integer then return a integer. However, I have trouble figure out the input of the function , could someone give me an example?

Comment: What makes you think `y` is a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't any input. `y` does not expect any parameter, it will only provides a list of function of type `Integer -> Integer` (or more precisely: `Num a => a -> a`).

How can it be useful?

Well, you can use it in many ways, some examples:

```
>>> let y = [\a->a+3, \b->1 , \c->c*c]
>>> map (\f -> f 3) y
[6,1,9]
>>> sequence y 4
[7,1,16]
>>> head y 10
13
```

Answer (score 2):

First, the actual type of `y` is `Num a => [a -> a]`, because integer numbers are polymorphic constants.

Second, `y` is not a function, it is a list. It does not take any arguments; its elements do. Or, if you want to call it a function, it has 0 arguments and returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

`y` is not a function, it's a *list of* functions.

There is no input. It's just a list of functions. You can pick one of these functions up and call it with some input, but as it stands, it's just a bunch of functions that have been put into a list.